# Capybara Poltergeist and Selenium different

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, capybara, poltergeist

```
  find(:css, "//input[@id='component_1']").set(true) #poltergeist
  # find(:css, "//label[@for='component_1']").click #selenium
```

I have an issue alternating between selenium and poltergeist:

The top find method only works in Poltergeist and I need to comment out the bottom one. The bottom method only works in Selenium and not Poltergeist.

I have to set the INPUT to true in Poltergeist and click the LABEL in selenium to work.

This is to select a radio button.

I would like one method that worked in both. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What errors do you get for each - and what is the html like?  Are some of the controls hidden via css?

Comment: Could you please choose a better title? It is very unclear what you want from the title alone.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're passing XPath selectors to `#find` while telling it they are css -- its pure chance either of those works - you probably want

```
find(:css, 'input#component_1').set(true)
```

or just

```
check('component_1')  # I'm assuming this is a checkbox due to setting true/clicking label being enough
```

if the checkbox is hidden then you won't be able to set it in which case you should be able to do the following

```
find(:css, 'label[for=component_1]').click
```